# Aditional shortcut for Grab+Axis

Tags: modeling, shortcut

I want to speed up the process of modeling. So, instead of using G and then choosing the axis (X or Y) I want to use the Key 1 and then 2 or 3 (which are close to each other and I do not need to see the keyboard)

But There are two problems.

1. I know how to change the Grab shortcut (Right clicking on the menu) But I do not know how to add the shortcut instead (I do not want to disable the default G shortcut)
2. I dont know how can I add a shortcut to the X and Y axis.

I'm using Blender 2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional bindings for existing operations can be added in the Keymap Preferences.

Open up Edit > Preferences, and on the left column select 'Keymap'.

You can search for operators by name, although that doesn't help if we don't know the name, of course. It appears the one you're looking for is under:

```
> 3D View > Mesh > 3D View Tool: Move >
```

Under a plethora of options for this tool, there's a section further down that says 'Transform Modal Map', which lists all the bindings for all the sub-parts of the move tool. And at the very bottom of that binding list, there's a button 'Add new' which allows adding extra keybindings.

Set your new binding to the desired keys, performing the same actio that the existing G, X, Y and Z keys are set to already.

Comment: I will try this. I do not want to "Change it" I want to add an aditional one. Thanks.

Comment: I had actually only noticed the 'add new' button towards the end of writing my first answer. So I've shortened/edited the above answer to just directly address what you asked. Hope it works as intended!